# How can I use Leaflet.Clusters with two maps in tabs and multiples geoJson properties?

Tags: leaflet, cluster-computing

I'm here because I read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33143237/cluster-multiple-layers-with-markercluster) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51544086/using-several-marker-cluster-groups-displays-overlapping-clusters/51549989#51549989)

I'm looking for some help to use the SubGroup plugin.

I'm building a map like this

```
var cartoDb = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
        subdomains: 'abcd',
        maxZoom: 19
    });
```

then I'm adding code for custom markers, like this

```
 var ccl18Icon = L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({
        prefix: 'fa', //font awesome rather than bootstrap
        iconColor: 'white',
        markerColor: 'orange', // see colors above
        icon: 'ambulance' //http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/
    });
```

I add my map

```
var map = L.map('map')
        .addLayer(cartoDb)
        .setView([46.85, 2.3518], 6);
```

Then I create an OnEachFeature function, inside of which I get all my geoJson properties, and a "layer.on" function. Like this

```
 function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {

        var html = '';
        if (feature.properties.Myfirstproperty) {
            html += '<p class="myfirstproperty">' + feature.properties.Myfirstproperty+ '</p>';
        }
        (....more html)
        layer.on('click', function() {
            $('#layer_infos .fill').html(html);
            if (L.Browser.mobile) {
                $('#infos').addClass("slide"); 
                $('#filters').removeClass('slide');
                $('.hamburger').text('Sélect something').fadeIn();
             }
        })
```

I duplicate this part because I have two maps in tabs, only changing the id and class of elements

Then I get all data from geoJson file

```
  var promise = $.getJSON("examen.json");
    promise.then(function(data) {
        var all = L.geoJson(data);


        var ccl18 = L.geoJson(data, {
            filter: function(feature, layer) {
                return feature.properties.Category == "ccl18";
            },
            onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
            pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

                return L.marker(latlng, {
                    icon: ccl18Icon
                })
            }
        })
```

After all this code, I create click functions to show hide layer, depending on chekcbox filters, something like this.

```
$("#ccl18").click(function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                map.addLayer(ccl18)
                map.fitBounds(allexamens.getBounds(), {
                    padding: [50, 50]
                });
                map.removeLayer(glucomarker)
            } else {
                map.removeLayer(ccl18)

            }
        });
```

I post all this code because I don't know if I can use the SubGroup plugin with my configuration.
What I'm looking for, is to let user click on multiple checkbox filters and to cluster markers even if they are from different categories; For the moment, I can cluster each group separatly, but not different groups together.
I saw this code, from the plugin author :

```
var parentGroup = L.markerClusterGroup().addTo(map);

var overlays = {};

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i += 1) {
   overlays['Group ' + i] = L.featureGroup.subGroup(
   parentGroup,
   getArrayOfMarkers()
  ).addTo(map);
 }

 L.control.layers(null, overlays, {
  collapsed: false,
 }).addTo(map);

 function getArrayOfMarkers() {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
   result.push(L.marker();
 }
 return result;
 }
```

but I don't understand how to implement it.. Does someone managed to make it work with geoJson data ?
Any help would be appreciated !!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok finaly I found my solution.

I'm using markercluster plugin only.

When I get the geoJsonfile datas, I add the following

```
var promise = $.getJSON("examen.json");
    var clusters = L.markerClusterGroup(); // a new cluster group for my first map
    var clusterade = L.markerClusterGroup(); // a new cluster group for my second map
    promise.then(function(data) {
```

In my click actions (checkbox filters) I add my layer to the cluster group, and not to the map directly, as I was doing before . Something like this :

```
 $("#ccl18").click(function() {
            if (this.checked) {

                 ccl18.addTo(clusters);
                map.fitBounds(allexamens.getBounds(), {
                    padding: [50, 50]
                });
            } else {
                 clusters.removeLayer(ccl18);
                 map.fitBounds(allexamens.getBounds(), {
                    padding: [50, 50]
                });
            }
        });
```

It's an if statement that says : "add layer to cluster if I click on the checkbox, otherwise remove layer". And I add a fitBounds to the parent layer which let me zoom-out from the cluster.

I add this code to all my checkbox actions.

Then, at the very end of my file, I juste add the clusters to the maps.

```
clusters.addTo(map);//my clusters for my first map
clusterade.addTo(map2);//my clusters for my second map
```

So now, when I check two checkbox, the cluster is shown on the map

[image]

And when I click on the cluster, I can clearly see my different markers.

[image]